# How do I iterate over `*[]struct` in golang?

Tags: go, struct

I am dynamically creating structs and unmarshaling csv file into the struct. After unmarshaling I get the populated variable of type `*[]struct{}`. I am able to to a `fmt.Printf("%v", theVarible)` and see all the values printed as `&[{} {}]` . How do I loop over this?

code snippet :

```
f, err := os.Open(csvFile)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

instance := dynamicstruct.NewStruct().
        AddField("Integer", 0, `csv:"int"`).
        AddField("Text", "", `csv:"someText"`).
        AddField("Float", 0.0, `csv:"double"`).
        Build().
        NewSliceOfStructs()

if err := gocsv.Unmarshal(f, instance); err != nil {
    utils.Capture(errors.Chain(err, "Unable to unmarshal csv file"), true)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to dynamically create struct using this library ( https://github.com/Ompluscator/dynamic-struct) and using this library gocsv ( https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv )  to Unmarshal

Comment: If the output of your printf is literally `&[{} {}]` then that means the gocsv.Unmarshal didn't work as you might expect.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for such language fundamentals. Use a for loop after dereferencing the pointer (obvious). Stop using Printf for "debuging" or trying to inspect your data as Printf does too much magick. If a simple for loop over the dereferenced pointer doesn't work this means that your data is not of type *[]struct.

Comment: The output of my Printf is `&[{v1 v2} {s1 s2}]` . 
@Penelope Stevens use a map for?

Comment: @ssbb191 as an alternative to the answer by I-Love-Reflection you could use the reader as demostrated in the readme of the package you're using: https://github.com/Ompluscator/dynamic-struct#make-a-slice-of-dynamic-struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to access the elements of a dynamically defined slice type:

```
instance := dynamicstruct.NewStruct().
    AddField("Integer", 0, `csv:"int"`).
    AddField("Text", "", `csv:"someText"`).
    AddField("Float", 0.0, `csv:"double"`).
    Build().
    NewSliceOfStructs()

if err := gocsv.Unmarshal(f, instance); err != nil {
    utils.Capture(errors.Chain(err, "Unable to unmarshal csv file"), true)
}

// The concrete value in instance is a pointer to 
// the slice of structs. Create the reflect value 
// and indirect with Elem() to get the reflect value
// for the slice.
slice := reflect.ValueOf(instance).Elem()

// For each element of the slice...
for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {

    // slice.Index(i) is the reflect value for the
    // element.  
    element := slice.Index(i)

    // element.FieldByName returns the reflect value for 
    // the field with the given name.  Call Interface()
    // to get the actual value.
    fmt.Println(element.FieldByName("Integer").Interface(),
        element.FieldByName("Text").Interface(),
        element.FieldByName("Float").Interface())
}
```

[Run an example on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CCn9Zy2AJTP).